# Using multiple data triggers does not work

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I want to detect when the selected item changes in a `ListBox` and a `TreeView` via `DataTrigger`s

so this is my code

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DirTreeView, Path=SelectedItemChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=DirTreeView, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource contentConverter}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listbox, Path=SelectionChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=listbox, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource contentConverter}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

if i comment out the last `DataTrigger` it works fine, but when I use both nothing works.

Why is that and how do I get this to work using both triggers?

Comment: I would recommend to check debug output for BindingErrors

Comment: `SelectionChanged` is not a property of the ListBox class, hence you can't bind to it. Same for `SelectedItemChanged` in TreeView. Both are events, not properties.